Inconsistent HTTP Visibility in Wireshark for Azure API Calls from C# vs. Python and CURL
I am using the Azure API to get audio for words. This is my code in C#, and it worked fine until I noticed that for some words it returns empty audio.
       string subscriptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STT_API_KEY");
       Authentication auth = new Authentication("https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken", subscriptionKey);
       try
       {
           accessToken = await auth.FetchTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
           //Console.WriteLine("Successfully obtained an access token. \n");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //Console.WriteLine("Failed to obtain an access token.");
           //Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
           //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           return null;
       }

       string host = "https://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1";

       // Create SSML document.
       XDocument body = new XDocument(
               new XElement("speak",
                   new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                   new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en-US"),
                   new XElement("voice",
                       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en-US"),
                       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "gender", "Female"),
                       new XAttribute("name", "en-US-AvaNeural"), // Short name for "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, Jessa24KRUS)"
                       text)));

       using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
       {
           using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage())
           {
               // Set the HTTP method
               request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
               // Construct the URI
               request.RequestUri = new Uri(host);
               // Set the content type header
               request.Content = new StringContent(body.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/ssml+xml");
               // Set additional header, such as Authorization and User-Agent
               request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
               request.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               // Update your resource name
               request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME");
               // Audio output format. See API reference for full list.
               request.Headers.Add("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", "riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm");
               // Create a request
               //Console.WriteLine("Calling the TTS service. Please wait... \n");
               using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
               

To investigate the issue, I tried calling the same API through other means: directly via CURL and also through Python with this code.
endpoint = 'https://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1'
ssml = """
<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'>
  <voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Female' name='en-US-AvaNeural'>
    black
  </voice>
</speak>
"""

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml',
    'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'audio-16khz-32kbitrate-mono-mp3'
}

response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=ssml, verify=False)
To my surprise, I was able to get the audio for words that I couldn't get through C#.
I wanted to compare the requests to understand why I am not getting the same results in different cases. To do this, I opened Wireshark and configured TLS to use SSLKEYLOGFILE so that I could see the frames unencrypted. I ran the request through Python and saw in Wireshark that an HTTP request with all the parameters I set was being made. However, when I ran the request through C# and filtered by the address, I didn't see any HTTP request at all (only TCP and TLS), and the same happened with CURL.
I tried to find the reason why HTTP requests might not be visible, and the answers I saw suggested it was because the traffic is encrypted. However, I saw that the decryption worked when the code was run from Python. Why should there be any difference based on which code the request originates from?

Is this on Windows? If so I bet dotnet (C#) uses Schannel and doesn't implement SSLKEYLOGFILE. Curl supports a dozen TLS stacks and you don't say which your build is using, but according to this only some support SSLKEYLOGFILE. Since you control the client, why don't you change it to send cleartext (HTTP) to something that forwards as HTTPS, like squid or even just socat or stunnel? Then you can log or capture that clear side.

There is currently no support in the .NET Framework for writing the pre-master secret to a file that Wireshark needs to decrypt TLS.
There are a few options:

use an intercepting proxy such as mitmproxy to decrypt the traffic
write the decrypted data from your C# application using PcapStream and open that in Wireshark.

Maybe the discussions in this question or this github topic can help you.
